# Angular 2- images inside select drop down is always 0X0 pixels. Image loaded but not displayed in chrome

Tags: css, angular, drop-down-menu, angular-ngselect

A select drop down in my angular 2 app doesn't show my images associated to options, though the images are working when I isolate from select drop down. Some CSS is overwriting my images in select - I can load image but can't display it. Here's my code:

```
<form>
    <select [(ngModel)]="ddselectedStatus" name="statusselect" style="width:320px;" (ngModelChange)="onStatusChange($event)" class="col-xs-8 form-control">
        <option value="">--Select Status--</option>
        <option  [ngValue]="i" *ngFor="let i of myOptions">
            <img src="images/opened.png" class="rowindic"/>
            {{i.name}}
            </option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Your code ,It's not possible, as <option> only supports text.
You need to find other ways, search for "select option images"

Answer (score 0):

its just a matter of CSS. This should help but keep in mind other CSS may also interrupt,

```
<img [style.width.px]="50" [style.height.px]="50" 
     [src]="images/opened.png" class="rowindic" />
```

Comment: Thanks @micronyks. But this didn't work. I am thinking if it is a browser issue. I am using chrome. Do I need to do something explicitly to make it work in chrome?